# Is it allowed to use the Spotify Web API for commercial projects?

Tags: terms-of-service

I have a simple question concerning the Spotify Web API.

Is it legal to retrieve data from this service as a base for my app which then should be commercial?

Without going too much into detail: I use the information to present the user an extra service based on this information.

The relevant paragraph on the terms & conditions is the following:

> Unless you receive Spotify’s written approval, the following are the only commercial uses of Non-Streaming SDAs permitted under these Developer Terms:
>
> sale of advertising, sponsorships, or promotions on the Non-Streaming SDA or Website;
>
> sale of, or sale of access to, a Non-Streaming SDA (including any e-commerce initiated via the Non-Streaming SDA);
>
> For the avoidance of doubt, you may not offer the metadata, cover art, or Audio Preview Clips or any other Spotify Content for any separate sale or charge or standalone product. For example, you may not offer access to metadata or cover art conditional on the purchase of tokens or credits or any other in-app payment feature. Further, you may not sell the Spotify Platform, Spotify Content, or Spotify Service or access to any of the foregoing.

Source: https://developer.spotify.com/developer-terms-of-use/

Since I'm not a lawyer I'm a bit unsure, but I think the last part is interesting:

> For example, you may not offer access to metadata or cover art conditional on the purchase of tokens or credits or any other in-app payment feature.

Since I'm selling an app offering access to metadata (as a base at least), is that critical?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Bye

Comment: Hi @The_Unknown, 3 years later do you know more about this? Did you have any issues following the sell of an app that accesses metadata?

Comment: I ended up not using spotify but musicbrainz ;-)

Comment: Did you do this choice "for safety", because you were unsure about what the developer terms of use meant? or are you actually sure we cannot use the Spotify metadata for a commercial app?

Comment: In fact I did it because spotify did have way less data than musicbrainz.